# How to put column of same height using overflow on one of them?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap. I have 2 columns working like this:

```
---------------------
| Content  | Aside1 |
|          |------- |
|          | Aside2 |
---------------------
```

The idea is to put the Content at the same height than the Aside1 and Aside2 incorporating an overflow:scroll to the content.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container-full">
  <article class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
    <p>Long content there</p>
  </article>
  <div class="aside_full_screen">

    <aside class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      <p>Social Network Content</p>
    </aside>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
      <p>Kitten Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
 article{ 
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: rgba(240, 116, 90, 1);
  overflow: auto;
  height: 1200px; /* — Just there for example, had to be remove — */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {   /* — For hiding scrollbar — */
    display: none; 
}
```

[Here](http://hpics.li/19c4fe3) is what I mainly got. And [here](http://hpics.li/a73d649) is what I want to achieve. A little precision, the scrollbar is hidden. I'm open to JavaScript, jQuery, or any kind of proposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your **HTML** add aside1 and aside2 like so:

```
<div class="container-full">
  <article class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
    <p>Long content there: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
  </article>
  <div class="aside_full_screen">

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 aside1">
      <p>Social Network Content</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 aside2">
      <p>Kitten Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can use jQuery to call a function on document ready and window resize. Inside the function, you need to calculate `.aside1` and `.aside2` height with the [height()](https://api.jquery.com/height/) function. Then apply the `total` (aside1 + aside2) to `article`.

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(myfunction);
$(window).on('resize', myfunction);

function myfunction() {
  var aside1 = $('.aside1').height();
  var aside2 = $('.aside2').height();
  var total = aside1 + aside2;
  $('article').css("height", total);
};
```

See an **[example CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbbJvQ)**.

Comment: Yeah that would work but actually i'am working with responsive content so if i resize the page, the columns will not be the same height anymore.
But thank you for your quick answer.

Comment: Hum neither because the columns are done with a % of the width of the page so the height is changing  all-along the resize.
Ps : You can use overflow: auto to automatically the overflow-x.

Comment: Could you please explain better what you are trying to achieve? Maybe if you have some css code could you include that in your post?

Comment: Done, if you still want to have a look :)

Comment: Nup id like to have what ever the size of the screen (bigger than 991px) the both columns joint at the same height, that way it form a single block.
As it is shown in the second screen.

Comment: Yeah that's absolutely this !

Comment: Yeah thank you, i'll propose you to edit it just a bit so it works on document ready. Plus i have to put a minimum height on the article or the content2 would be put to the right. But Yay ! That worked ! Thank you :) !
I have edit my post so you can eventually edit your answer :)
Thanks a lot ! Sadly i cant up vote you yet, too less reputation, sorry :(